# Counting pixels on raster image

Tags: qgis, elevation

I have a raster file that show forest cover, very simple, where there is a green pixel there is forest. I need to count how many of this pixels fall under a certain elevation. I have the elevation already calculated and so on. I only need to relate these two features. Like, how much forest are there in different elevations. I am just starting working with QGIS, so I am sorry if the questions is too stupid.

Comment: Is your elevation a raster or a vector layer with polygons? Do you really want to count pixels or rather area units?

Comment: They are both raster layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reclass forest as value 1 and other pixel as NoValue. Then I would make different rasters depending on the altitude( Same value and NoValue). Then I would multiply the raster "forest" and the other rasters (1 by 1) with the raster calculator.

There likely are a lot of other techniques, but the logic stays the same. (mask X mask )

Comment: Hey thank you very much. I think that you probably work.